# Mix Blend Mode Bleed

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I have a div with some text and a background image I am blending in with mix-blend-mode: darken.
However the background image is bleeding outside of the text.
I am using Orbitron-Black as the font but I cannot see that making a difference!
Here is my code.

```css
.big-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin: 80px 10% 0 10%;
  position: relative
}

.text-parallax {
  background: url('https://iam.theweb.engineer/assets/text-1.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
  display: inline-block
}

.text-parallax-content {
  font-family: 'Orbitron-Black', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 8.8em;
  line-height: 120%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #232323;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  -ms-mix-blend-mode: darken
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section">
  <section class="big-text">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-parallax" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.86">
        <div class="text-parallax-content">Bleeding Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have made a fiddle here.
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s4a8rk4f/1/)

Comment: is this what you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/s4a8rk4f/2/   _similar to `background-clip:text;` actually_  or https://jsfiddle.net/s4a8rk4f/3/

Comment: Awesome, thats a lot better, however the background I would prefer it to be #232323 but that dont seem to work on the box shadow

Comment: with a bit of contrast maybe ? https://jsfiddle.net/s4a8rk4f/5/